# PHP/MySQL Count() Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a class registration system for a client that utilizes PHP and MySQL.  I have the database and table all set up and that part works just fine, however, the client has requested that upon registration, if there are 3 or fewer students enrolled to warn that the class may not run.

I'm trying to use the count() function as well as passing a dynamic variable from a cookie, set from the registration PHP script.  However, I've hit a roadblock.  I can't seem to get the count() function to actually count the rows.  My select statement is below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$class = $_COOKIE["class"];

$min_check = "SELECT class_list, COUNT(class_list) as count 
              FROM T_Student WHERE class_list = '$class' 
              GROUP BY class_list 
              HAVING count < 20";
$result = mysql_query($min_check);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count < 4)
{
  echo "IF THERE ARE 3 OR FEWER PEOPLE SIGNED UP FOR THIS CLASS, IT MAY NOT RUN.\n";
  echo "THERE ARE CURRENTLY " . $count . " PEOPLE SIGNED UP.\n";
}
else if ($count > 4)
{
  echo "There are currently " . $count . " people signed up for this class.";
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use both the MySQL `COUNT()` procedure and PHP's `mysql_num_rows()`; use one or the other. Also, what does `echo $count` give you?

Comment: You should be a little more careful with naming your variables. You do three different things with variables and field-names you all call count. Use something more descriptive like count_classes or $count_rows to avoid being dazzled.

Answer (score 5):

Your SQL query is returning a list of the `class_list` values, along with a count of each specific instance, where there are less than 20 people registered.

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

...is getting the number of records returned in the resultset, not the alias `count` value, which is why you aren't seeing the output you expect.  You need to read into your resultset to get the value:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $count = $row['count'];

  if($count < 4) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the input.  I knew it was something pretty easy that I needed to add, just been looking at it too long to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using known MySQL identifiers like `count`. It's confusing.

```
$class = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE["class"]);

$min_check = "SELECT class_list, COUNT(class_list) as mycount 
          FROM T_Student WHERE class_list = '$class' 
          GROUP BY class_list 
          HAVING mycount < 20";
```

Don't forget to escape the contents of that cookie!

<strike>The error is that `count` is a reserved word. You need to either surround it in backticks `` `count` `` or even better, use a different moniker.</strike>  It's not an error per se, but it's just too confusing.

Next up, you are not actually retrieving the `mycount` result from the database. I suggest using code something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($min_check);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $people_count = $row['mycount'];
    if ($people_count < 4) { echo "this" }
    else { echo "that" }
}
```

Comment: Factually incorrect. "Names of built-in functions are permitted as identifiers but may require care to be used as such. For example, COUNT is acceptable as a column name. " (from the MYSQL documentation, chapter 8.3

Comment: Count can be used unquoted like this. Try it and see. Very true about escaping though :)

Answer (score 0):

The count that you want is returned in the row of the query. the mysql_num_rows will count the rows returned, which is not what you want. Use this instead.

```
$result = mysql_query($min_check);
$count = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $count[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance, the `HAVING count < 20` is unnecessary.

You use the MySQL-count-function, but never retrieve it's value!? Use:

```
$firstRow = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $firstRow[1]; // 1 indicates the second column (0 being the first)
```